# Name of app is different after download

Tags: xcode

I just submitted an app. The name of the Xcode project is slightly different then the name I gave in my iTunes connect. For some reason after I download the app in the App Store it shows the name of my Xcode project. Is there a way to adjust this easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update your app to App Store with adjusted `.plist`.

Change the **Bundle Display Name** in `.plist` to the name you want. Still, this requires to go through the App approval process again.

Comment: So and even though the Xcode project might still be called differently when archiving as long as the .plist Bundle Display Name is correct then that's the name it will show when someone downloads the app, the name that's mentioned in the .plist correct?

Comment: Awesome, Thank you so much Raptor !